# Javascript SVG viewer library

Tags: javascript, svg

I search for javascript svg viewer library which is smooth zoom and drag and move viewport.
I found [SVGPan](http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/). But it's not work smooth.
Is there any other library?

Comment: I have the same problem. May be, we can change the handleMouseWheel function to do this no?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this very powerful library: http://leafletjs.com/

It's used for showing interactive maps, but I use it to display images (and SVG) smoothly, with zoom, drag etc:

http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html

Answer (score 1):

There's [this](https://jwatt.org/svg/tests/zoom-and-pan-controlsViewBox.svg) which you works with any browser or there's a [Firefox extension](http://www.treebuilder.de/zoomandpan/index.htm)